# Problem with getting data from html in RoR controller

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to make a product cart.
I want to be able choose the quantity of product when i add the product to cart.

This is LineItemsController

```
    class LineItemsController < ApplicationController
  include CurrentCart
  before_action :set_line_item, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :set_cart, only: [:create]

  def index
    @line_items = LineItem.all
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @line_item = LineItem.new
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
    @line_item = @cart.add_product(product)
    @line_item.quantity = params['q'].to_i

      if @line_item.save
        redirect_to @line_item.cart, notice: 'Item added to cart.'
      else
        render :new
      end
  end

  def update
      if @line_item.update(line_item_params)
        redirect_to @line_item, notice: 'Line item was successfully updated.'
      else
        render :edit
      end
  end

  def destroy
    @cart = Cart.find(session[:cart_id])
    @line_item.destroy
    redirect_to cart_path(@cart), notice: 'Item successfully removed.'
  end

  private
    def set_line_item
      @line_item = LineItem.find(params[:id])
    end

    def line_item_params
      params.require(:line_item).permit(:product_id, :quantity)
    end
end
```

This is view/line_item/_form.html.erb

```
<%= simple_form_for(@line_item) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.association :product %>
    <%= f.association :cart %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

This is view/product/show.html.erb

```
    <% content_for :body_class, 'bg-light' %>

<section class="section instrument-show">
  <div class="columns">
    <div class="column is-8">
      <%= render 'shared/breadcrumb', category: @product.category %>
      <h1 class="title is-2"><%= @product.title %></h1>

      <!--ul class="pv1">
        <%# if @product.brand? %>
        <li class="inline-block pr3"><%#= @product.brand %></li-->
        <%# end %>

        <!--li class="inline-block pr3"><%#= @product.model %></li-->

        <%# if @product.condition? %>
        <!--li class="inline-block pr3"><%#= @product.condition %></li>
        <%# end %>
      </ul-->

      <div class="feature-image">
        <%= image_tag(@product.image_url(:default).to_s) %>
      </div>

      <div class="content pa4 mt3 bg-white border-radius-3">

      <h3 class="subtitle is-4">Description</h3>
      <%= @product.description %>


      <h3 class="subtitle is-4 pt5">Product Specs</h3>

      <table class="table is-narrow">
        <% if @product.category.present? %>
        <tr>
          <td class="has-text-weight-bold">Category:</td>
          <td><%= link_to @product.category.name, @product.category %></td>
        </tr>
        <% end %>

        <%# if @product.finish %>
          <tr>
            <td class="has-text-weight-bold">Finish:</td>
            <td><%#= @product.finish %></td>
          </tr>
        <%# end %>

        <tr>
          <td class="has-text-weight-bold">Model:</td>
          <td><%#= @product.model %></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column is-3 is-offset-1">
      <div class="bg-white pa4 border-radius-3">
        <h4 class="title is-5 has-text-centered"><%= number_to_currency(@product.price) %></h4>
        <p class="has-text-centered mb4">Sold by <%#= @product.user.name %></p>

        <form>
          <input type="number" name="q" min="1" max="50" step="1" class="input label">
        </form>


        <%= button_to 'Add to cart', line_items_path(product_id: @product), class: 'button is-warning add-to-cart' %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <% if user_signed_in? && current_user.admin? %>
    <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_admin_product_path(@product), class: 'button' %>
  <% end %>
</section>
```

Now in this string `@line_item.quantity = params['q'].to_i` from

```
<form>
  <input type="number" name="q" min="1" max="50" step="1" class="input label">
</form>
```

i'm getting "nil" and i desperately don't now what should i do to get actual number.

P.S. This is view/line_items/new.html.erb

```
<h1>New Line Item</h1>

<%= render 'form', line_item: @line_item %>

<%= link_to 'Back', line_items_path %>
```

Comment: can you upload your view/line_item/new.html.erb

Comment: Yes. I've done it.

Answer (score 0):

new.html.erb is to enter your data and if you submit, the data will flow to create method inside your controller, meanwhile show is just to show the data, and you cannot input form inside show, 
my suggestion try to put q part of new.html.erb, and put it inside simple_form_for tag 
since it is number, you can use number_field rails tag helper as sample below, with name :q and range between 1 .. 50 with step 1, below is the sample probably can help your problem

when you submit from new.html.erb, you will receive params[:q] as part of parameters and save it with create method

```
<%= simple_form_for(@line_item) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <%= number_field(:q, in: 1.0..50.0, step: 1) %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.association :product %>
    <%= f.association :cart %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. I think, because view/line_items/new.html.erb and view/line_items/_form.html.erb never rendered. And button "submit" for create new lineitem placed on view/product/show.html.erb. So i hoped that there is a method or ability to get the number of product in lineitem from view/product/show.html.erb.